# How to set limit for Nginx log files on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, nginx

Nginx occupies all the available disk space. How to set limit for log files on Mac OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotate the log files. On OS X, `newsyslog` is the preferred utility to do that. Set up a file like this in `/etc/newsyslog.d/nginx.conf`:

```
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/nginx.log     deceze:wheel     644  2     1024 *     J
```

Read https://www.newsyslog.org/manual.html for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: shoudn't a `SIGUSR1` signal be sent to the nginx master process? Or this can be skipped because the log file is not deleted but set to empty?

Comment: @Paolo Good point, I cannot actually answer that with certainty. You probably should.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @deceze's answer, here's an adapted version of Apple's Apache configuration for a Homebrew-installed `nginx`:

```
#logfilename                            [owner:group]  mode count  size   when  [flags]  [/pid_file]                       [sig_num]
/opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/access.log  _nginx:_nginx  644  10     20480  *     Z        /opt/homebrew/var/run/nginx.pid   30
```

This is assuming you're running as user:group `_nginx:_nginx`. It sends the correct `SIGUSR1` signal (30 on macOS) to `nginx`. Also changed to using `gzip` instead of `bzip2`.